# Is it possible to generate a list of all Net names in Altium Designer

Tags: schematics, altium

If I have a schematics in Altium Designer and it is spread over 10 sheets then is it possible to generate a list of all net names that are used in it? How can I generate this list? I want to do this to double check if a certain Net name is miss-spelled at one or more places in any sheet.

Comment: Depends on your version of Altium, but there is a net-list option under FILE -> EXPORT in Altium 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a netlist report of the whole project via the menu option Design->Netlist for Project and then you can choose the netlist format that us wish the report to come in. The options for the netlist formats will be dependant on which netlist generators you have installed. The report you generate you should be able to search the nets you are looking for or print out and review as you like ! 
You could also use the Navigate Plane under the "Net/Bus" and also search for the net you are looking for - the benefit here is that when you click on the net it will zoom into the location of the net on the schematic

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a net length report, which tells you all the net names and the length of all the tracks assigned to each one.

> I tried to find this option in Altium v14.3 but cannot find it. Can you tell how to generate this net length report in this version or any later version?

In the PCB view, open the PCB pane. Select Nets, and from the net classes select .

[image]

Now right-click in the area where the individual nets are listed and choose "Report...".

Comment: I tried to find this option in Altium v14.3 but cannot find it. Can you tell how to generate this net length report in this version or any later version?

Answer (score 1):

For making net lists from schematic

1.Choose Parameter Manager

[image: Choose Parameter Manager]

2. Set Options - Nets and click OK

[image: Set Options - Nets and click OK]

3.Select All & Report

[image: Select All & Report]

It will create Excel file with all nets in design